# How to use WebProxy with RestSharp?

Tags: restsharp

I would like to know how to use `WebProxy` with `RestSharp`. I am using version `108.0.1` and the code given below returns `407` when running locally from my workstation, which should use my credentials.

```
   var client = new RestClient("https://www.google.com");
   var proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://mycorpproxy.com");
   proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
   client.Options.Proxy = proxy;
   var request = new RestRequest();
   request.Method = Method.Get;
   var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the proxy in the options when you create the client, not after. In v107, the options object properties were init-only, but it fails on legacy SDKs, so we had to revert it to setters, but setting the options that are used to create an `HttpClient` instance after the client is created has no effect.

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("http://mycorpproxy.com") {
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://www.google.com") {
    Proxy = proxy
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```